# SQL DELETE highest value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a list of rooms with each assigned a room number. I would like to delete the highest room number:

```
DELETE FROM rooms WHERE roomNb = (SELECT max(roomNb) FROM rooms LIMIT 1)
```

I would expect this to work but when I try to execute this query in PHP I get this mysqli_error:

```
string(64) "You can't specify target table 'rooms' for update in FROM clause"
```

Comment: The 今 草 顿 웃 answer is correct. Check this SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79ea1f/2

Comment: And the zamnuts answer too, more simple without the use of a JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason to use a subquery/join... why not just shift the row off the top of a table after an `ORDER BY` clause?

```
DELETE FROM rooms ORDER BY roomNb DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

try using join,

```
DELETE a
FROM   rooms a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT max(roomNb) maxroom FROM rooms) b
          ON a.roomNb = b.maxroom
```